# Telerik RadGrid with different types of edit controls

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have to dispay a list of fields. Some are editable and some are not. Those that are can be different types, such as text fields, dates, times, or boolean. I'm using Telerik's RadGrid. See screen shot for a test project I made.

Questions:
In the item created handler, why are there 4 cells? I had to fill in cells[2] and cells[3] for the values to display. I set AutoGenerateColumns to false, and I only have two GridTemplateColumn definitions.

Why does the item.RowIndex incrment by two's and go up to twenty? When I have 10 rows.

Is there a better way to do this?

Here's how I declared the grid:

```
        <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="Grid1" Width="100%" Height="500px" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        OnItemCreated="OnGridItemCreated"
        OnNeedDataSource="OnGridNeedDataSource">
        <ItemStyle Wrap="true" />
        <AlternatingItemStyle Wrap="true" />
        <ClientSettings>                    
            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="false" />
            <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" />
            <Resizing AllowColumnResize="true" ClipCellContentOnResize="true" ResizeGridOnColumnResize="true" EnableRealTimeResize="true" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView>
            <NoRecordsTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblNorec1" runat="server" Text="No records"></asp:Label>
            </NoRecordsTemplate>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="FieldDisplayName" HeaderText="Field Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="FieldValue" HeaderText="Value">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

/

```
/ grid needs datasource
    protected void OnGridNeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        // create a DataSource
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Field_Display_Name"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Field_Value"));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Field_Display_Name"] = "Item Id" + i.ToString();
        dr["Field_Value"] = "Value" + i.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    Grid1.DataSource = ds;
}

// grid item is created
protected void OnGridItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;

       // fill in cells 2 and 3. Why are there 4?

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "Field " +  item.RowIndex;
        item.Cells[2].Controls.Add(lbl);

        switch (item.RowIndex)
        {
            case 2:
            case 8:
                RadTextBox txt = new RadTextBox();
                txt.ID = "RadTextBox1";
                txt.Text = "hello " + item.RowIndex;
                item.Cells[3].Controls.Add(txt);
                break;
            case 4:
            case 10:
                RadDatePicker dp = new RadDatePicker();
                dp.ID = "RadDatePicker1";
                dp.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
                item.Cells[3].Controls.Add(dp);
                break;
            case 6:
            case 12:
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                item.Cells[3].Controls.Add(cb);
                break;
            default:
                Label lbl2 = new Label();
                lbl2.Text = "Value " +  item.RowIndex;
                item.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lbl2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I switched to the OnItemDataBound event and used ItemIndex instead of RowIndex. That gives me an index value from 0-9

Evidently columns 0 and 1 are always created for command items. Instead of referrering to by index, I changed to unique column name.

// set the text in the first column
item["FieldDisplayName"].Text = "Field " + index;

// add a control in the secon column
RadTextBox txt = new RadTextBox();
txt.ID = "RadTextBox1";
txt.Text = "hello " + index;
item["FieldValue"].Controls.Add(txt);

Answer (score 1):

If the grid reflects your actual needs, I would suggest you go with an HTML table inside an ASP FormView. You can map out most of the things you've shown here right in the HTML. There are plenty of FormView tutorials out there, it looks like more of a solution for what you're after. Don't let the complexity of trying to squeeze that stuff into a radgrid get you going in the wrong direction.

If you want to show say 10 records at a time, that's where the gridview/radgrid comes in handy, if it's just one record at a time, look to the formview.

EDIT: I just noticed this was asked like a year ago. I hope you aren't still waiting on an answer for this one!